# Adding data to wp_sitemeta table

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Is there a way to add a row to the wp_sitemeta table in Wordpress Multisite? I'm thinking just like for wp_usermeta, there are functions such as add_user_meta( $user_ID, $meta_key, $meta_value), add_user_meta( $user_ID, $meta_key, $meta_value) and similar, there might be a way to do the same for wp_sitemeta?
I have searched, but can't seem to find information about adding to this table anywhere. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to add. You can use $wpdb

```
<?php 

global $wpdb;
$main_blog_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix(BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE);

$meta_table  = $main_blog_prefix."sitemeta";

$insertedRow = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prepare(
    $meta_table , 
    array( 
        'site_id' => BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE, 
        'meta_key' => 'some_meta', 
        'meta_value' => "asd asd asda sda sda sd"
    )
  )
);


?>
```

Comment: Remember to use the prepare statement  like :

`$wpdb->insert(  $wpdb->prepare(  . . . . . ) ) `

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

WordPress provides the function `update_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, [$prev_value])` (see the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_metadata)) that can (and probably should) be used for this. It will update the key value if it exists, and add it if it does not exist.

To update `wp_sitemeta`, set `$meta_type = 'site'`. The `$object_id` should be the network ID, which is almost certainly "`1`". (WordPress only supports a single network with ID "`1`" via its UI, although the WP DB has schema support for multiple networks.) The `$meta_key` and `$meta_value` parameters are for the metadata key and value, respectively.

Note too that `wp_sitemeta` is for network-wide options, not for blog-specific (child site) options.

If you're able to work at the shell command prompt and have access to the WP-CLI command line client, you can also use the `wp network meta update <id> <key> [<value>] [--format=<format>]` command. (I have not tested whether this adds or updates as needed, but I expect it does.)